# small loop unix with user input

Tags: loops

I want to cat the lines of a csv file using "cat ~/Desktop/file.csv" in a loop using an input user path and when I execute this command in the terminal it works but not with the loop.

When I execute this script it works perfect :

```
for line in $(cat ~/Desktop/file.csv);
    do echo $line;
    done
```

I execute a small script in my desk by clicking on an icon : algo.command and I enter this path : ~/Desktop/file.csv

**my script is :**

```
read -p "Enter the path of your file :" path

for line in $(cat "$path");
do echo $line;
done
```

**and I have this output :**

> cat: ~/Desktop/file.csv: No such file or directory
>
> [Process completed]

Thank you for your help

Comment: yes thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` is not replaced by `/home/<your login name>` as you expected because you read a string and you get it as it is, the shell does not  interpret it like in your working case.

You have to give the path without using `~` except if you do the substitution in the script by yourself :

If your script is executed by bash :

```
read -p "Enter the path of your file :" path

if [ ${path:0:2} = "~/" ]
then
  path=${path/\~/$HOME}
elif [ ${path:0:1} = "~" ]
then
  # suppose ~<user name>
  path=${path/\~/\/home\/}
fi

for line in $(cat "$path");
  do echo $line;
done
```

---

Example having that script in /tmp/s

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo ~
/home/pi
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ (echo aze ; echo qsd) > ~/aze
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat ~/aze
aze
qsd
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ bash s
Enter the path of your file :~/aze
aze
qsd
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ bash s
Enter the path of your file :~pi/aze
aze
qsd
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bash /tmp/s
Enter the path of your file :aze
aze
qsd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```